# R ggplot2: How can I use the aesthetics argument as part of a function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, user-defined-functions

I want to define a function that has several histograms as an output. My inputs are: A dataframe, a variable for binwidth and the name of the "x-variable" in Aesthetics. Unfortunately, the code does not work, so I may need to specify the input differently. Can anybody help here? the code is given below:

````
```
histograms <- function(InputData, my_binwidth, my_xvariable) {
  hist_template <- ggplot(aes(x = my_xvariable, y=..density..), 
                          data = InputData) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth=my_binwidth)


  hist_unscaled <- hist_template +
    scale_x_continuous() +
    labs(title = "No Scaling") 

  result <-  list(hist_template=hist_template,hist_unscaled=hist_unscaled)
  return(result)
}

testhist <- histograms(WineData,0.1,residual.sugar)  ```
````

Comment: p.s. "residual.sugar" is the name of a column in the dataframe "WineData", so WineData$residual.sugar is a variable.

Comment: I thought that in ggplot, the command "aes(x=my_xvariable..." expects the name of a column in InputData as an input. It works like this when I use ggplot in the usual manner, i.e. outside of a function. my_variable is a name, not the variable itself. But this does not seem to work if I perform this whole procedure within a function...

Comment: Instead of `aes`, you can use `aes_`, which accepts strings with variable names

Comment: I would back @konvas but would like to add that `aes_string` is much reliable and clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this if you wrap the variable in `rlang`'s `enquo` function:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rlang)

new_histograms <- function(InputData, my_binwidth, my_xvariable) {
    var <- rlang::enquo(my_xvariable)
    hist_template <- ggplot(aes(x = !!var, y=..density..), data = InputData) +
        geom_histogram(binwidth=my_binwidth)
    hist_unscaled <- hist_template +scale_x_continuous() +
        labs(title = "No Scaling") 
    result <-  list(hist_template=hist_template,hist_unscaled=hist_unscaled)
    return(result)
}

mtcars %>% new_histograms(4, cyl)
```